# How can I hide the menu bar in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, menubar

How can I hide the menu bar in visual studio code?
I do not find the command to do it. In some applications or browsers the **alt** key is used but I can not find the command or the option in the menu bar to hide it. Can you help me?

[image: screenshot].

Comment: Odd there is no keybinding shown in the View menu or the Keyboard Shortcuts; because ALT works perfectly fine for me to toggle the  menu bar (on Windows).

Comment: See my answer below - I did not mean to post that last comment!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can hide the menu bar by clicking the `Toggle Menu Bar` option in the `View` menu.

[image: Screenshot of option]

---

To bring the menu bar back, as pointed out by [pramesh-bajracharya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5753035/pramesh-bajracharya) in the comments:

`Ctrl + Shift + P` will open a command window and you can type Toggle Menu Bar to toggle it on and off.

Comment: **For future readers:** `Ctrl + Shift + P` will open a command window and you can type `Toggle Menu Bar` to toggle it on and off.

Comment: Actually, it will display simply by pressing "Alt" or "Option".

Comment: Not true any more as of April 2021

Comment: Not true anymore, as it got blended within the `Appearance` menu item, as a renamed sub-item called `Show Menu Bar`

Answer (score 33):

If you want to toggle the menu bar with Alt, see this setting:

> // Control the visibility of the menu bar. A setting of 'toggle' means that the menu bar is hidden and a single press of the Alt key will show it. By default, the menu bar will be visible, unless the window is full screen.

```
 "window.menuBarVisibility": "toggle",
```

The default is "default", change it to "toggle" in your user settings..

Comment: File->Settings->"window.menuBarVisibility": "visible"

Comment: "window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden" works for does looking to disable it on Alt key press.

Comment: @Anthony, try the toggle setting above.

Comment: @Mark tried it in zen mode hitting Alt triggers the menu, but if set to hidden menu doesn't apear

Comment: Not true any more

Comment: @LewisLevin The setting in the answer still works.